How to attack the shuffling of correlated numbers?
Suppose I have a function that accepts vector input $x$ and outputs vector $y=f(x)$. I want to protect the output $y$ through shuffling numbers in it. I hope the shuffling can confuse the attacker by hiding the position information. The ability of hiding position is indeed true when shuffling random numbers. However, the outputs $y$ is not uniform. A possible attack, for example, when $x_1$ and $x_2$ only differ a little, the $y_1$ and $y_2$ also differ a little. When receiving two outputs $shuffle(y_1)$ and $shuffle(y_2)$ that are shuffled differently, the attacker may match the order of $shuffle(y_1)$ and $shuffle(y_2)$ through the correlation of numbers.
I want to ask is there any similar known attack that can restore the shuffling?

The feasibility will depend on the domain of the random numbers. Are they reals? Integers? Finite alphabet? I assume the attacker knows the probability distribution.

All numbers are supposed on the ring, such as integers in $[-2^{l-1},2^{l-1}-1]$ and $l$ is the bit length. If the probability distribution you mentioned is for the output $y$, yes.
